# Lazy loading angular services using require.js

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, lazy-loading

I can lazy load a controller by doing the following,

**Step1:** Add an additional config...

```
rootModule.config([
    "$controllerProvider", function($controllerProvider) {
        rootModule.registerController = $controllerProvider.register;
    }
]);
```

**Step2:** Define the controller against the registerController defined in step 1

```
angular.module("rootModule").registerController("authController",
 function ($scope, $location, $rootScope, authService) {
     $scope.userName = "";
     $scope.userPwd = "";
     $scope.authenticate = function ()...

     $scope.testFunction = function ()...

 });
```

**Step3:** load the controller during routing by doing this,

```
 rootModule
    .config([
        '$routeProvider',
        function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/',
                {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/Login.html',
                    resolve: {
                        load: ["$q", function($q) {
                            var defered = $q.defer();
                            require(["Controllers/authController"], function() {
                                defered.resolve();
                            });
                            return defered.promise;
                        }]
                    }
                }).
```

**Now, the problem is I have a service called "authService", which I would like to lazy load, how to do it?** Here is the service...

```
define(function() {

angular.module("rootModule").service("authService", function ($http) {
    return {
    /////Something code here//////
   });
});
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy). It is a different approach than yours, but you may still get ideas. Lazy loading in Angular is not a simple thing.

Comment: Thanks dude... will do it as soon as possible, hopefully I'll get enough info to answer my own question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was very simple in the end, thanks to [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs) great blog written by Dan Wahlin.

To load a service in run time according to the routing, I had to do this...

**Step 1:** Get a reference to $provide.service() method in my rootModule's (module which contains the routing info) config...

```
rootModule.config(["$controllerProvider","$provide",
    "$controllerProvider", "$filterProvider","$compileProvider", function ($controllerProvider, $provide) {
        rootModule.registerController = $controllerProvider.register; //for controllers
        rootModule.registerService = $provide.service; //for services
        rootModule.registerFilter = $filterProvider.register; //for filters
        rootModule.registerDirective = $compileProvider.directive; //for directives
        rootModule.registerFactory = $provide.factory; //for factory
    }
]);
```

**Step 2:** Register the service to be loaded dynamically

```
define(function() {
angular.module("rootModule").registerService("reviewReportsService", function () {
    return {
              sampleData: "This is some sample data"
           }
       });
});
```

**Step 3:** Resolve the service script file, to load when the respective route is loaded

```
when('/ReviewAndSubmit',
                {
                    controller: "reviewAndSubmitController",
                    templateUrl: "templates/ReviewAndSubmit.html",

                    resolve: {
                        load: ["$q", function ($q) {
                            var defered = $q.defer();
                            require(["Controllers/reviewAndSubmitController"], function () {
                                defered.resolve();
                            });
                            require(["Services/reviewReportsService"], function () {
                                defered.resolve();
                            });
                            return defered.promise;
                        }]
                    }
                })
```

Hope this helps someone....